# convert from LinearLayout to Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to converting from LinearLayout to Relative layout but when I do that, there is an error showed up in the activity class: 
 cannot resolve symbol R

```
 buttonRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

what can I do ?

Comment: put all your code here, including the imports

Comment: Clean your project, rebuild project.

Comment: We cannot help with the information provided. Paste your code, at least the Activity code and the XML section of the 'buttonread'

Comment: Thanks Alex Mamo , it's work

Comment: @FUN please accept my answer if u want.I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, please Clean your project and than rebuild project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project.
Then Rebuild your project.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is Some Resource error as can not resolve R problem is commonly faced when resource error.If not just clean and rebuild project it will eventually go away.